# jqPlot - Pie chart data highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, jqplot

When I hover over a pie it shows me the name and score but on the top-left side only. What I want is when I hover over a right pie it should show me the highlighted data on the right side, and similarly for a bottom right pie the highlighted name and score should appear on the bottom-right side.

Here is my jqPlot code for pie

```
var a=2;
var c=2;
var t=2;
var i=2;

var plot4 = $.jqplot('pie3', [[['A',c],['B',t],['B',a],['D',i]]], {
                   seriesDefaults:{
                   shadow: false, 
                   renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
                   rendererOptions:{
                   sliceMargin: 4, 
                       // rotate the starting position of the pie around to 12 o'clock.
                   startAngle: -90,
                   showDataLabels: true,
                        dataLabels: 'value',
                        dataLabelFormatString:'%.1f'

                  }
                } , 
                  
                grid: {         
                    background: 'transparent',
                    borderColor: 'transparent',
                    shadow: false,
                    drawGridLines: false,
                    gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                    borderWidth: '0'
                }
            });

       $('#pie3').bind('jqplotDataHighlight', 
        function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data, radius) {    

            var chart_left = $('#pie3').offset().left,
            chart_top = $('#pie3').offset().top;

          var color = '#337ab7';
          $('#tooltip1b').css({left:chart_left+radius+5, top:chart_top});
          $('#tooltip1b').html('<span style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:' + 
          color + ';">' + data[0] + '</span><br />' + 'Score : <span style="font-weight:bold;">' + parseFloat(Math.round(data[1] * 100) / 100).toFixed(2) + "</span>");
          $('#tooltip1b').show();
        }); 

      // Bind a function to the unhighlight event to clean up after highlighting.
      $('#pie3').bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight', 
          function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
              $('#tooltip1b').empty();
              $('#tooltip1b').hide();                 
          });
 });
```

Comment: It would be really nice if you can put up a fiddle (instead of picture) to see the current behavior in action.

Comment: @DavidR my fiddle is not generating the chart ..i do not know why

Comment: Can you please post the fiddle link. Let me check.

Comment: @DavidR https://jsfiddle.net/sarthakfx/g5ufg021/

Comment: Seems, you have not mapped your core JS files through (CDN) under the  "External Resources" section in the right hand side

Comment: @DavidR now fiddle is working but data highlighter does not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125922/discussion-between-sarthak-srivastava-and-david-r).

Answer (score 0):

Well, All you need to do is to add the `highlighter` attribute to your code as,

```
highlighter: {
  show: true,
  useAxesFormatters: false,
  tooltipFormatString: '%s'
},
```

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g5ufg021/8/

Hope this helps!